# PHP function to get N random values (as array) which's sum result in X

Tags: php, algorithm

I think the subject hits it better than I was expecting.

I need a function which returns random numbers which result in a given value (X) when they are summed up.

Something like this:

```
getRandomTo(10); // result for example: array(2,3,5)
getRandomTo(10); // result for example: array(4,3,3)

getRandomTo(12); // result for example: array(5,1,6)
```

I could not find a generic algorithm function for solving that requirement. Further more I cannot imagine a *FAST* and *performant* way to create something like this my self.

Please help me out

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Get a random number for 1 to Number, then get random number from 1 to Number - sum of the previous result until number - previous results = 0

Comment: Instead of thinking of an algorithm to find numbers to add up to a total, think of a way to partition the total into the number of values you want in a random fashion.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research or minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getRandomTo($num)
{
    $x = Array();
    $i = 0;
    do
    {
        $x[$i] = rand(1,$num);
        $num = $num - $x[$i];
        $i++;
    }while($num > 0);
    print_r($x);
}
```

Comment: The average for the first number will be half the total. Does this match the distribution that @serjoscha is expecting as a result?

Comment: @serjoscha didn't provide any such requirement as to the randomness of the numbers. just that they add up to the input.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do this:
create a random value between 0 and X; say this one is called r1. save this in your array.
create another random value between 0 and (X-r1), name it r2. save it also.
do these steps as often as you need it (or as long as r1+...+rn is lower than X)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
function randomTo($numIn) {
    $numOut = 0;
    $numbers = array();

    do {
        $add = rand(1, $numIn);
        if($numOut + $add > $numIn)
            continue;
        $numOut += $add;
        $numbers[] = $add;

    } while( $numOut != $numIn );

    return $numbers;
}


$result = randomTo(15);
var_dump($result);
```